# Locking custom toolbox properties and metadata using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, metadata, arctoolbox

I created a custom toolbox, made of models, for a client. I used ArcGIS Pro 1.0.1.

I would like to know if it is possible to "lock" the metadata and the properties  of the toolbox models, so that the client cannot change the credits, the description, the version number...

I haven't found a lot of information on the subject. This post seems to say it is not "advisable" : [ArcGIS - Is It Possible To "Lock" Metadata](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60575/arcgis-is-it-possible-to-lock-metadata)

However, the toolbox is to be delivered as a file (it will not be published) and the locking is required, hence this question : is there a way to lock or freeze, or set a password on properties and metadata of a model in a toolbox ?

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend you update ArcGIS Pro to latest version for bug fixes and lots of new functionality.  You are using a very old version of ArcGIS Pro so I can't say if it is possible as I don't remember it being an option 5 years ago...

In latest version of ArcGIS Pro you can certainly protect the model with a password, you simply set it in the property dialog as highlighted below.

[image: Property window of a model]

This will protect the model logic but the metadata sits outside of this protection and is not lockable.

For what its worth, my experience is that most users don't even know how to change the metadata...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, I had tried setting a password and then changing the metadata : I could changed them, so I thought this was a problem on esri's side. However I just tried editing my model and it is locked with a password. Too bad for the properties and metadata. (Unfortunately the version is imposed by the client, I have no say in it).

Comment: I would recommend you try to influence your client to upgrade, v3 is superior to v1 and it will be free to upgrade! Crazy they haven't.